# Actionbar TextColors overriden when using Theme.Material

Tags: android, android-styles

I building an application that uses ActionBarSherlock. I won't use ActionbarCompat so please focus on my question.

I made some code that can change the title color, as well as the subtitle color on the ActionBar. However when using my styles.xml for v21+ it will override those colors with the stock white colors (provided in Theme.Material)

Now I want to ask; what do I have to change in my code below to actually remove the Theme.Material colors override?

-EDIT

I noticed that it is working only when using a TextView in the Actionbar, however that's not what I want.

```
 <style name="Theme.App.NoLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/abs__holo_blue_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/dark_holo</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dark_holo</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar.NoLight</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar.NoLight</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
    </style>
```